# Display left <TD> to the right of right <TD>

Tags: c#, html, css

I've got a table with two tablecells:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>[Left]</td>
<td>[Right]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is a simplification of a control I'm using (System.Web.Ui.Webcontrols.Wizard).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to display the left column on the right like this:

```
[Right] [Left]
```

I've tried JQuery and it works like it should BUT you can see the screen flicker when its moving the content. This because of the page which renders then executes the JQuery.

I've also tried influencing the rendering of the control only then I lose the EventHandlers for the Menu or the Content (depending on which cell I move)

My question:

Is it possible to use CSS to accomplish the result I need?

OR

How can I manipulate the Wizard control to get the menu on the right side.

Comment: I wouldn't mess with tables like this.

Comment: @Kyle I do agree but I still need some kind of solution to my problem. Best would be not to misuse CSS but when left out of options I'll take it.

Comment: using dir="rlt" instead of default ltr, look on http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html

Comment: You say that the screen flickers, when do you try to run the JQuery code? Maybe you should try the DOM ready: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Adam I do use that. IE just isn't that fast between rendering HTML and then execute JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use a ASP.Net control adapter. This article may help you to understand how it works : [ASP.NET 2.0 Control Adapter Architecture](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/21/asp-net-2-0-control-adapter-architecture.aspx).

The key idea is to override the standard rendering of the wizard control to a custom render method of your own.
Then you will be able to virtually produce any output. It can be a bit tricky in some case though.

[edit] According your comment, you will be able (if you are lucky) to rely on the [ASP.Net CSS control adapter](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/) shipped by Microsoft. The original target of these adapters is to generate a clean W3C compliant html (using div) instead of the standard rendering (based on tables).
If the wizard control produces a table, you can maybe use a combination between the css adapters and a custom CSS file that can play with "float:left" and "float: right" styles to swap columns.
I didn't try, but it merits to be looked at.

Comment: Definitely will be looking into this!

Comment: I don't know especially the wizard control, but you will probably have to dive a bit in the code of the control. Complex controls in ASP.Net are often subdivided into smaller controls. The adapter maybe will have to target not the wizard itself but one its sub control type.

Comment: There's an internal table somewhere in there

Comment: @rdkleine: if the wizard use a asp:table control within, take a look at my edit.

Comment: I does look promising. Hopefully I can get it to work in Sharepoint without too much hassle.

Comment: actually you can also with sharepoint. I wrote an [article](http://blog.hand-net.com/sharepoint/2010-04-23-sharepoint-2007-personnaliser-le-comportement-par-defaut-dun-type-de-colonne-natif.htm) that may help you. The article targets SP2007, and is in french, but you can read the code quite easily. Just be careful on the wide impact of this technic. The code in your adapter should check if the parent is a wizard to avoid full breaking sharepoint.

Comment: also take a look at the [Accessibility kit for SharePoint](http://aks2007.codeplex.com/) that can do the plumbing for you, and you can "simply" (funny word in sp world) change your css styles.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
<table dir="rtl">
```

By having it Right-to-left you make the cells appear in reverse order, achieving your desired effect. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uA8SF/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var tempContentOfRightCell = $("#right").html();
$("#right").html($("#left").html);
$("#left").html(tempContentOfRightCell);
```

should work. Remember to give id's of right and left to your cells.